# Configuring net beans for j2me [kubuntu]

Tags: netbeans, java-me

I'm running **Kubuntu** and I wanted to create simple application in j2me, so I installed the WTK2.5.2 SDK(thats the latest one supported by Linux) and started programming the application using a combination of *Kate* and *emacs* (can't get the code completion to work).

Anyway the application works fine when I compile it using the *ktoolbar*, which is present in the WTF2.5.2/bin folder. But coding the application without Code Completion is quite a tedious task so I thought I might as well use an IDE like ***Netbeans***( 6.5 via apt-get ), which offers Code Completion as well as several tools for building a GUI.

Now the problem is that Netbeans doesn't recognize J2ME even when I try adding it manually via the Tools->Java Platform Menu. (See this screen shot - http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/4736/netbeans.jpg). I just can't click the next button.

And If I directly try to create a project there is no option for using J2ME.

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you need to install the mobility plug-in?

Edit: via Tools->Plugins ofc

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked.
Unfortunately I've already coded over 80% of the application, but at-least it works now !! :-)